# Custom NPM package throwing Error during build

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I forked a project and made some changes to it and wanted to make use of it in my project. so in my **React** projects **package.json** I made a reference to this forked link and it is working fine in *development*. The main issue arises when I'm pushing it to my container and now the build fails.

https://blaipratdesaba.com/how-to-use-an-npm-node-module-that-has-been-forked-b7dd522fdd08 mentions about using the **package.json** script called **postinstall** to help with the issue, are there any alternatives to this?

Answer (score 0):

What's the error when the build fails to run in the container?

If you don't want to use npm's **postinstall** you could always write a script that you run before or after you issue the install command. (This is not that different from using **preinstall/postinstall**)

Maybe something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd - && npm install 
cd node_modules/my-package && npm my-script
```